# How do I make a common table header when one <td> has a <table> within it?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having an issue with html table. This seemingly basic HTML table formation is taking longer than expected.
I have a table where I need a common header with `<thead>` and `<th>` elements.
One of the `<td>` in the `<tbody>` has a table within it with no headers.

In a case like this, I need a common header in the main `<thead>` which aligns and forms in accordance with the  in the main table and also the `<td>` in the child table within on of the `<td>` in main table.

I have tried using `<td>` inside `<tbody>` instead of `<thead>` to solve this problem and many other things like introducing dummy td in the main table. It did not help.

This is the requirement:

[image: Requirement]

This is my code:

```
<table  class="table  table-condensed table-hover table-bordered">
<tbody>
    <tr class = "meta">
        <td  widtd = "100px">Metaset&nbsp;</td>
        <td bgcolor="#E3E3ED" widtd = "50PS">Id</td>
        <td bgcolor="#E3E3ED" widtd = "40PX"> Release&nbsp;</td>
        <td bgcolor="#E3E3ED" widtd = "90PX">Component&nbsp;</td>
        <td bgcolor="#E3E3ED" widtd = "40PX">Status&nbsp;</td>
        <td bgcolor="#E3E3ED" widtd = "10px">MBC&nbsp; </td>
        <td bgcolor="#E3E3ED" widtd = "10px">MSC&nbsp;</td>
        <td bgcolor="#E3E3ED" widtd = "10px">IBS&nbsp;</td>
        <td bgcolor="#E3E3ED" widtd = "10px">S0&nbsp;></td>
        <td bgcolor="#CCCCD5" widtd = "140px">Release&nbsp;</td>
        <td bgcolor="#CCCCD5" widtd = "100px">Id&nbsp;</td>
        <td bgcolor="#CCCCD5" widtd = "100px">Family&nbsp;</td>
        <td bgcolor="#CCCCD5" widtd = "40px">Status&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody ng-repeat="(metaset, ids) in metasetHashSplit">
    <tr class = "meta">
        <td   rowspan = 100 width = "100px"><strong>{{metaset}}</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "meta" ng-repeat="item in ids" >
        <td  width = "800px">
            <table class="table  child table-hover table-bordered  " >
                <tr ng-repeat="buy in item.Buy  >
                    <td width = "50px">
                    {{buy.BuyId}}</span></td>
                    <td width = "40px">{{buy.BuyRelease}}</span></td>
                    <td width = "90px">{{buy.BuyComponentAffected}}</td>
                    <td width = "40px">{{buy.BuyStatus}}</span></td>
                    <td width = "10px"><span style="color:red">{{buy.MBC}}</span></td>
                    <td width = "10px"><span style="color:red">{{buy.MSC}}</span></td>
                    <td width = "10px"><span style="color:red">{{buy.IBS}}</span></td>
                    <td width = "10px"><span style="color:red">{{buy.S0}}</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td width = "140px"><strong>{{item.release}}</span></td>
        <td width = "100px"><strong>{{item.Id}}</span></td>
        <td width = "100px"><strong>{{item.family}}</span></td>
        <td width = "40px"><strong>{{item.status}}</span></td>
    </tr>
```

Essentially the following headers you see are for the table within the `<td>`

```
         <td bgcolor="#E3E3ED" widtd = "50PS">Id</td>
     <td bgcolor="#E3E3ED" widtd = "40PX"> Release&nbsp;</td>
     <td bgcolor="#E3E3ED" widtd = "90PX">Component&nbsp;</td>
     <td bgcolor="#E3E3ED" widtd = "40PX">Status&nbsp;</td>
     <td bgcolor="#E3E3ED" widtd = "10px">MBC&nbsp; </td>
     <td bgcolor="#E3E3ED" widtd = "10px">MSC&nbsp;</td>
     <td bgcolor="#E3E3ED" widtd = "10px">IBS&nbsp;</td>
     <td bgcolor="#E3E3ED" widtd = "10px">S0&nbsp;></td>
```

Kindly help me out with this !

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle

Comment: Is that valid to have a table inside a table?

Comment: @Lee of course it's valid when it is in `<td>`

Comment: Not clear at all what the specific problem is. Create a demo that provides an overview of the issue. Probably don't need to use `<table>` for all of the layout either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the 2 steps:

1) Use table heading for creating table headings and

```
<th colspan="3">    </th>
```

for merging cells in headings.

```
<thead>
<tr>
<th colspan="4">Group A
</th>
</tr>
```

```
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Release</th>
  <th>Component</th>
  <th>Status</th>
 </tr>
```

2) Don't use the "thead" for inner table which is inside td, so by this you will have only one table header and with a few CSS tricks you can make it sticky header and inner rows will be vertical scroll. It will be an awesome table for reporting.

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned it, you have to use colspan, You should be able to finish it.

```css
th{
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table  class="table  table-condensed table-hover table-bordered" border='1'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Metaset</td>
        <td colspan = '4'>Group A</td> 
        <td colspan='4'>Alerts Looking Up</td>   
        <td colspan = '5'>Group B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "meta">
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        
        <th bgcolor="#E3E3ED" widtd = "50PS">Id</th>
        <th bgcolor="#E3E3ED" widtd = "40PX"> Release&nbsp;</th>
        <th bgcolor="#E3E3ED" widtd = "90PX">Component&nbsp;</th>
        <th bgcolor="#E3E3ED" widtd = "40PX">Status&nbsp;</th>
        
        <th>S0</th><th>S1</th><th>S2</th><th>S3</th>
        
        <th bgcolor="#CCCCD5" widtd = "140px">Release&nbsp;</th>
        <th bgcolor="#CCCCD5" widtd = "100px">Id&nbsp;</th>
        <th bgcolor="#CCCCD5" widtd = "100px">Family&nbsp;</th>
        <th bgcolor="#E3E3ED" widtd = "90PX">Component&nbsp;</th>
        <th bgcolor="#CCCCD5" widtd = "40px">Status&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```